# What does the Strunk & White badge mean?

Tags: discussion, edit-badges

I understand what it takes to earn the [Strunk & White badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white), but where does the name of the badge come from?  What does the name mean or refer to?

Answer (score 63):

William **Strunk** Jr. & E. B. **White** were the co-writers of [The Elements of Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9562912639), a popular American English writing style guide.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style (via google)

Answer (score 23):

While the other answerers identified the style guide [*The Elements of Style*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) correctly, Strunk and White were not co-authors, at least in the traditional sense.

> William Strunk was a professor of English at Cornell about a hundred years ago, and E.B. White ... took English with him in 1919, purchasing as a required text the first edition, which Strunk had published privately. **After Strunk's death**, White ... was asked by Macmillan to revise and expand *Elements* for commercial publication.  It took off like a rocket (in 1959) and has sold millions.

(Emphasis mine.)

Taken from [a *Chronicle of Higher Education* article](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497) which goes on to criticize some portions of the book.

Comment: +1 simply for a fascinating link.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/50years.pdf) to the article which doesn't require subscription.

Answer (score 12):

Strunk & White are the authors of [The Elements of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style), an American English writing style guide.

Answer (score 5):

Look up the Elements of Style at Amazon. Strunk and White is a reference to the authors of the book on editing on which all editing practices have since drawn.

Comment: "on which all editing practices have since drawn" is... a bit hyperbolic at best.

Comment: @Popular Demand:  However, it might not be too far from the truth.  I'd expect anybody who writes usage guidelines to have studied S&W, and therefore it's conceivable that all usage guidelines in the US have been influenced by S&W.  I would expect most usage guidelines to have been influenced.